# Pygame help 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pygame

I have installed pygame for python 2.7 but this come up if I type import pygame

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

According to [pygame download page NOTE](http://pygame.org/download.shtml):

> windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.

Make sure you're using 32bit version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem recently, i have found that if you are using a 64 bit machine, then you need the  64 bit version of python and the 64 bit version of pygame. The 64 bit version of pygame is not available on the main website but you can download it from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I would suggest uninstalling python 2.7 and reinstall the 64 bit version of it from the python download page. when you install pygame, use the file called "pygame‑1.9.2a0.win‑amd64‑py2.7.exe" (without the quotes) on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it. I found a 64 bit pygame version at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Select **pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl** (for python 2.7) from the list of options available.

Copy the downloaded file to path/to/python27/Scripts

Then use pip installer.
Install **wheel package** first if you don't have it already. It is used to extract and install whl files.
Open cmd.

```
cd path/to/python27/Scripts
pip install wheel
pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Hope that solves it.